# How to copy locations from one feature class to another

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase

I am new to GIS and unfamiliar with the functionality of feature classes.

I am working on a project that has already been started. I have a geodatabase with one feature class. The feature class contains points and locations. I would like to create a new feature class in the same geodatabase using the same points/location that have already been established. Is this possible?

I tried copying and pasting the feature class but this does not copy any of the data. I have also tried copying the data from one table to another using Editor but this also has not worked. Finally, I tried to load data into the new feature class, however this only loaded the object ID's and not the location for the ID's.

Comment: A feature class can only contain one of either points, lines or polygons. Each feature class, table, or feature dataset in the geodatabase has to have a unique name.

Comment: A simple copy/paste in ArcCatalog should have worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [Copy Features](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/copy-features.htm) tool in ArcToolbox under `Data Management Tools->Features`, which will copy all data in attribute table as well as geometry.

[image]